# Issue on Mapping inherited class in .Net 4.8 with LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

I am using .Net 4.8 Framework and System.Data.Linq package.

I am trying to Map data from database to object (Child).

ChildClass inherits ParentClass, so in my thought it should be able to use Properties of ParentClass also. But I am not able to achive it.

I have tried below code so far

```
    public class TestClass
    {
        public void GetDataList()
        {
            try
            {
                using (var db = new DataContext(connectionString))
                {
                    string strSQL = "select 1 as ID, 'test' as Name, 5 as ChildID";
                    var ic1 = db.ExecuteQuery<ChildClass>(strSQL);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
    }
    public class ParentClass
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
    public class ChildClass : ParentClass
    {
        public int ChildID { get; set; }
    }
```

In this case, I am getting an Error.

> Data member 'Int32 ID' of type 'TestConsoleApp.ParentClass' is not part of the mapping for type 'ChildClass'. Is the member above the root of an inheritance hierarchy?

Comment: The code doesn't use LINQ at all, it just maps query results. If that's all you want, use a micro-ORM like [Dapper](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper). LINQ-to-SQL is a very old ORM that was replaced by Entity Framework and hasn't received any new features in over 10 years

Comment: What are you trying to do? The answer may be *use Dapper and `var children=connection.Query<ChildClass>(sql)`*.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Linq has not been in this example, but it has been used in actual senario.

Comment: Post the actual scenario then

Comment: I am able to solve the issue using LinqToSql and Dapper

Answer (score 0):

I able to fix the issue using Linq-to-sql and Dapper.

Linq-to-sql is used to support older code. and Dapper will fix the mapping issue.

Here is fixed code

```cs
using (var db = new DataContext(connectionString))
{
    string strSQL = "select 1 as ID, 'test' as Name, 5 as ChildID";
    var ic1 = db.Connection.Query<ChildClass>(strSQL);
}
```